# TileMap is not visible when I test it

Tags: godot, godot4

I added the tileset, began drawing the level, but its not visible when I start the game. The character body is on the tiles, so they should be visible.I tried looking on the settings of the TileMap, but everything seems to be ok.

[image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your main scene to the level. You have the player scene set as main scene. I had this problem. click on project, project settings, run. change main scene to whatever you are drawing on and it will show up.